# Allocation and release of object within a method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I just recently made the move to Objective-C. I am doing some exercises from [Kochan's Programming in Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325861). On this particular exercise, I am asked to modify the print method with and optional argument:

```
-(void)print{
  NSLog(@" %i/%i ", numerator, denominator);
}
```

For this I simply created another `print` method that would take a `BOOL` argument and modified the existing print method as follows:

```
-(void)print{
  [self printReduced:FALSE];
}
-(void)printReduced:(BOOL)r{
  if(r){
    [self reduce];
  }
  NSLog(@" %i/%i ", numerator, denominator);
}
```

But for the last part of the exercise, I am supposed to use that `BOOL` to determine if the Fraction should be reduced or not (no problem testing the flag), but when reduced I am not supposed to modify the original object. For this I allocated a new Fraction object inside the `printReduced` method and released it before the end of the method too:

```
-(void)printReduced:(BOOL)r{
  Fraction *printingFraction = [[Fraction alloc] init];
  [printingFraction setTo:numerator over:denominator];
  if(r){
    [printingFraction reduce];
  }
  NSLog(@" %i/%i ",[printingFraction numerator], [printingFraction denominator]);
  [printingFraction release];
}
```

My question is: Is it right to create and release objects whithin a given method this way? This seems to do the work just fine without modifying the original Fraction, but is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  Whenever you 'alloc' an object, you own it.  Before it goes out of scope (the end of the method in this case), you must relinquish ownership, a release in this case.

Comment: I think you meant to say `release` instead of `retain`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the last line meant to be `[printingFraction release];`? If you change it to that, your solution is correct. When you `alloc` an object you have to `release` it at some point.

Comment: It is. That is how I have in on my code, I simply typed it wrong on the question but thanks for the attention to detail. It is always good to know that there is always somebody meticulous going over your code.